# Yii2 - option default selection

Tags: php, methods, yii2

i have the below form field of dropdown list.My problem is default option selected is not happening.The option value is coming as POST request.

```
$_REQUEST['id']=8;

<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($model,'id','name'), 
        [
            isset($_REQUEST['id'])?'"options"=>[$_REQUEST["id"]=>["selected"=>true]]':'',
            'prompt' => 'Select ',
            'onChange' => '$.get("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('data/datalist?id=').'"+$(this).val(),function(data){$("#dashboard-id").html(data);})',
        ])
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have done the mistake in options.Try like below:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($model,'id','name'), 
        [
            'options'=>isset($_REQUEST['id'])?[$_REQUEST["id"]=>["selected"=>true]]:'',
            'prompt' => 'Select ',
            'onChange' => '$.get("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('data/datalist?id=').'"+$(this).val(),function(data){$("#dashboard-id").html(data);})',
        ])
    ?>
```